# Retriving full Date from an API and formatting afterwards

Tags: jquery, regex, date, replace, format

I am retrieving a date from an API with format:

```
Thu, 13 Dec 2012 12:59:05 +0200
```

Note that the above format is a printed as a string and **I would like to format it as such**:

```
Thu, 12:59
```

What would be the easiest way without using jQuery replace() so many times?

Comment: Use DateJS (http://www.datejs.com/) . When you have to absolutely, positively have to manipulate a date, accept no substitutes.

Comment: I wouldnt want to use an entire plugin just for a single scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this--

```
var st = "Monday, 9 Jan 2012 12:59:05";
var dt = new Date(st);
var m_names = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue","Wed", "Thu","Fri", "Sat");
var dayInNum =dt.getDay();
var desireDate = m_names[dayInNum] + ","+ dt.getHours() +":"+ dt.getMinutes();
alert(desireDate);
```